# How to run commands between curl and bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

It's now quite common to run installation script this way:

```
curl -L http://example.com/install.sh | sudo bash
```

What if I want to set an alias just for this script?

```
alias foo="bar -qux"; curl -L http://example.com/install.sh | sudo bash
```

won't work, because `bash` spawns its own separated process which has its own environmental settings.

Bottom line, I hope this can be done in single line.

Comment: It might be common but you should never do this...

Comment: Do you mean, you want `foo` inside `install.sh` to be treated as `bar -qux`?

Comment: @chepner yes, that's what I want!

Comment: Aliases aren't meant to be used as a hook for modifying runtime behavior.

Comment: @chepner so what other choices do I have? (without using `alias` commands?)